Frozen OS error when walking the file tree of an external drive
I want to normalize filepaths (removing accents) in an external drive and I use os.walk(). At one point, the script freezes and after I cancel, I see this message:
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "~/normalize_filepaths.py", line 2
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(target, topdown = False):
  File "<frozen os>", line 377, in walk
KeyboardInterrupt

Here is a snippet of the relevant code, the second
def normalize(fp):
    """
    >>> normalize("/Volumes/MM_BUP/MIGUEL/Acólitos")
    '/Volumes/MM_BUP/MIGUEL/Acolitos'
    >>> normalize("/Volumes/MM_BUP/MIGUEL/Acólitos")
    '/Volumes/MM_BUP/MIGUEL/Acolitos'
    >>> normalize("'This is my cup.' _ ゼロコ ZEROKO _ 紅茶の遊び方 _ mime _ clowning-8MgRJAXn1tE.mp4")
    "'This is my cup.' _  ZEROKO _  _ mime _ clowning-8MgRJAXn1tE.mp4"
    >>> normalize(" großer Tag")
    ' grosser Tag'
    """

    fp = fp.replace("ß", "ss")
    
    name_clean = unicodedata.normalize('NFD', fp)
    return name_clean.encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode("ascii")


def main(target="/some/path"):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(target, topdown = False):
        for name in files + dirs:
            filepath = os.path.join(root, name)
            clean = normalize(name)
            new_filepath = os.path.join(root, clean)
            shutil.move(filepath, new_filepath)

How can I avoid this frozen OS error and visit all files and directories?

Hello. What is normalize? I mean, which method is it?

@gthanop Does it matter? The exception is happening inside os.walk(), not normalize().

<frozen os> is not an error, it's the name of the file containing the code that was running when the exception happened. I suspect it's related to the idea of "freezing" a python module: https://wiki.python.org/moin/Freeze

I don't know if it matters. I know I cannot reproduce. normalize helps produce each new file path inside the loop (which ultimately alters the file system directory /some/path which you are walking). Modifying the directory while walking it, seems like a problem (infinite loop maybe? I don't know).

KeyboardInterrupt is the exception that's raised when you type Ctl-C. If you don't have a try/except that catches it, this is the normal message you see when doing that.

It's a bit worrying that you might be modifying the names of directories while at the same time you're in the middle of walking those directories?  Have you tried adding topdown=False to your os.walk so that subdirectories have already been walked before trying to modify a directory name?

@gthanop I added the normalize function in the question.

@gthanop I walk the directories with topdown=False, or the deepest files first, so I don't think it should go into an infinite loop.

@Barmar I hit Control-C myself after several minutes of waiting, and it seems the script is frozen.

@FrankYellin I do use topdown=False in the call to os.walk().

Thank you for your cooperation providing the function. Since the normalize was not given previously, I was thinking that clean could contain anything really (including for example as many .. as were needed such that new_filepath was lying even outside /some/path, or it could for example contain exactly what was needed each time such that new_filepath was always the same file let's say, or anything really). But now normalize is given and I will try to investigate.

Does the script hang if you replace the inner loop body with just pass?

Sorry, I cannot reproduce the error at the moment. I tried with names like the ones in the documentation of normalize, as well as ascii only ones. Tried also with symbolic links and always used onerror argument and printed all the file paths. It worked fine everytime. I am using Python 3.13.0 (if related). I also couldn't produce infinite loop by renaming files within root. normalize indeed seems to me now also unrelated to be honest.

Maybe you have a lot of (small) files in a single directory (which slows down os.walk so when you interrupted it you get the error in that method usually)? Just guessing though. Can you reproduce the error with a small number of those files?

@Barmar The script does not hang if I replace the inner loop body with just pass.

@gthanop Following the tip form Barmar, you are right: it's not an error. It's simply that the loop takes a long time, and that it seemed stuck in one directory with 14 GB and 3650 files (in the directory and subdirectory) because it printed nothing for 10 minutes, even though I would think that treating a directory would be very quick (especially if it has no accents). When I leave it running for 20 minutes, then it finishes. Thank you for your help! Could you please write an answer and I'll accept it?

In order to reproduce the problem, I tried:

File names suitable for being modified by normalize (such as the ones documented in that method's comments). ASCII only names were tried too.
Symbolic links, along with normal files (empty and non-empty).

...and it worked just fine every time (for some toy example file system hierarchy). So I failed to reproduce, which means I didn't try it in the applicable way.
Your stack trace though does not indicate (at least as far as I see) an error in the code somewhere necessarily, but rather that you interrupted it at some point (you got a KeyboardInterrupt, which seems to happen upon canceling the code yourself, which is something that your post states you did). So it seems the program was not responding. According to my experience, when a code segment freezes (or seems to freeze), the first possible causes that come to my mind to investigate are:

Deadlocks. This can happen for example when accesing shared resources in a competitive consumers' environment. Assuming the simplest scenario, ie that your code is run on a single thread and process, the only way I can imagine there could be a deadlock in your snippet is inside implementations of the methods you call, ie methods in the imported modules os, shutil, and unicodedata which you call. But these modules, being Python standard library ones, I trust and feel confident that will not have any race conditions, but even if they have, I just don't know how they are implemented internally and cannot investigate them in a timely manner (ie it is expected as a most effort and unprobable success attempt), so I left this scenario to be investigated last, in favor of the simpler following ones.
Infinite loops. Here, it came to my mind that maybe shutil.moveing a file from its original name to a new name, inside the same root path, could result in producing a new result/file from os.walk. But then this file would be again shutil.moved and so on. I tried this with a purposedly alternating file name, but failed to produce an infinite loop, and then realized firstly that this shouldn't be the case in your code, judging from how you implement the new files' name generation (for example normalize(normalize(filepath)) should be the same as normalize(filepath), according to some tests and reading some documentation at least, so no new path would be generated then), and secondly because according to the documentation of os.walk the returned values are of types str and list (which indicates that they are filled beforehand and not while being iterated).
Actual lengthy processing. Here the first thing to blame for me is that the code is dealing with read and write operations from secondary storage media (ie your hard drive). Both os.walk and shutil.move are possible candidates then. The former I assumed (based on past observations) that can easily be a lengthy process in case you are running the code on directories with many files. The latter can obviously be lengthy in case of large files. But since you are so far getting the KeyboardInterrupt inside os.walk and not shutil.move then doing the operation on many files could explain a lengthy os.walk, while these being small could minimize shutil.moveing time at the same time, so I just assumed the first case (os.walking many files) first.

In order to have progress towards ruling out deadlocks' case, or verifying infinite loop case, or ruling out the case of os.walking many files, the simplest way would be to add some print statements inside the inner loop. Of course you can't detect as easily (with simple print statements) the case of shutil.moveing large files (unless you have access to shutil.move), but I would suggest to start with the easy stuff first and just put some print statements inside the inner loop. As a bonus, with print statements, you can verify generated file paths are legal (as an effort to rule out the possibility of the problem being to normalize an unusual path for example), as well as in the intended format.
To be honest I didn't test a large number of files to stress the above reasoning though, but since you confirmed in the comments that this is indeed the case and suggested to post this as an answer, then I did so. I am certain there must be more problematic scenarios to think of for freezing code, but I am glad that the actual scenario was found and I contributed for you finding it (hehe).
